# Asana API - How to add multiple tags when creating task?

Tags: javascript, api, asana, asana-api, asana-connect

As the title says, how do i add multiple asana tags when creating task? I have this

```
var task = {
      "data" : {
          "name" : projectName,
          "workspace" : getAsanaWorkspace(),
          "team" : teamId,
          "notes": desc,
          "tags": [{"id: 123245"},{"id: 456987"},{"id: 124589"}]
        } 
  };
```

but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making the tags list just a list of ids rather than a list of hashes?